# Build docker in ASP.NET Core: "no such file or directory" error

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm getting an error when I build my docker.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 1/8 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
 ---> 2628aaa7b8cf
Step 2/8 : ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:5000"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5dffde204fef
Step 3/8 : ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3064358bc0eb
Step 4/8 : ARG source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4159d0eb78c0
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 61a394c84304
Step 6/8 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7c2309f7085
Step 7/8 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
lstat obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
```

Here's my Dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectTestApi.dll"
```

and I run a command:

```
$ docker build -t my-docker-image-test .
```

Do you have any ide what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**It's happening because you didn't published your solution.** The error message is self-explanatory:

```
no such file or directory
```

By default, when you add **Docker support** to you ASP.NET Core Visual Studio 2017 project, it creates a bunch of `docker-compose.yml` files, one of them is `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` which handles the build process. Then, when you build the project through Visual Studio, full `docker-compose` pipeline is executed.

The contents of `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`, are similiar to this (it depends on custom config and project names obviously):

```
version: '2'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-1.1
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./SolutionName.sln && dotnet publish ./SolutionName.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

As you can see in the last line, there is a `dotnet publish` command invoked, which actually builds & publishes your project.

So the **solution for your issue**, will be just building the project before calling docker:

```
dotnet publish ./SolutionName.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish
docker build -t my-docker-image-test .
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Where should I add those two lines? In Dockerfile  for my project?

Comment: @GSPdibbler These are command line commands so the same place you would run the docker CLI. Probably a bat file.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the option "Add Docker Support" in Visual Studio 2017, VS generates a bunch of docker-compose files and Dockerfiles. As Marcin Zablocki mentioned, one of these is `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`.

To stay in line with the Docker philosophy, you can use a docker container to publish your project. To publish your project you would take the following steps:

1. `git clone/pull` your project & cd into the root dir
2. Publish your project with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml up`
3. Start your project with `docker-compose up`

I have encountered situations where the `Dockerfile` of your main project is giving problems. This happens with `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1`, you can change it to `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2` or whatever version is needed for your project.

Comment: VS.net 2017 17.4 does not create docker-compose.ci.build.yml nor does it call for this file from the commandline it generates.  Anyone have an idea how this now works because it's still broken.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this command works ok (copying from the output window of VS2017) ```docker-compose  -f "docker-compose.yml" -f "docker-compose.override.yml" -p dockercompose17560113652152234329 --no-ansi build```

Answer (score 0):

If you have published your project and facing this issue because of directory error, just move the docker file one folder up and put it beside *.sln file.