# Docker - No Such File or Directory (dotnetcore)

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

Completely new to docker - trying to spin up a dotnetcore web app on Docker (DockerToolbox on Win7) and facing this error.

[image]

Here's my:

- Docker file:

[image]

- Docker-compose.yml file:

[image]

This is a completely new project and i have mounted my

- C: Drive
- Project root directory

What could be the problem here?

--EDIT--
Just to point it out that yes I've also published my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by following: [Build docker in ASP.NET Core: "no such file or directory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387693/build-docker-in-asp-net-core-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

The fix is to publish your project first. Earlier i was doing it in a wrong way. We can do that by:

> dotnet publish ./**SolutionName**.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish

And then follow it up by

> docker-compose up

I did add some port mapping as well and here's my updated...

- Docker File

[image]

- Docker-compose.yml

[image]

And the URL was to access it was:

> http://192.168.99.100:3131/api/values

Hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the docker-compose the arg that is missing, 
I think you are sending a path or some like that

```
 context: .
  args:
    - buildno=1
    - gitcommithash=cdc3b19
```

Please see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#args

Comment: Thank you for replying!